# One website not loading in IE, occurring only on our LAN though

Tags: internet-explorer, networking, firewall

On our LAN, the website connect.media (or https://www.connect.media, doesn't matter what URL variation is used), will not load in Internet Explorer (rolled back to version 8 from version 11, doesn't load in either version though), but it loads in Firefox and Chrome (albeit slowly in Chrome)). The interesting part is when I connect to a hotspot or go through a proxy site, it will load in IE, and I even plugged directly into our demarc and it loaded in IE without any issues (we use Spectrum MRS, haven't had much luck with them troubleshooting which is why I'm here now).

The most similar issue I've come across when searching is post #37657920 on stackoverflow.com ("Website loads pefectly local but only title on network"). The [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhdWy.png) I'm seeing when using developer tools is "Object doesn't support this property or method", and it seems to be referencing Google Tag Manager/javascript and also an advertisement ("var Ad=function() {return"&tc="+qc.filter(function(a){return a}.length}"), which I could see causing issues as Google Ads Services is inaccessible from our network.

Back to developer tools, I've attached a picture of the errors it is logging in the console, I apologize as I have no background in development so I can't elaborate much on what I am seeing, but I did search "js?id=UA-63619913-2" and it brought up absolutely nothing.

Just possibly looking for some insight or tools I can use to troubleshoot further to maybe point our ISP in a specific direction, or if googleadservices will be the obvious culprit here.

Comment: Try to check and unchecked TLS and SSL options one by one in advanced tab in IE options and check whether it solves the issue or not. Also try to disable the Enhanced Protected Mode to check whether it help to solve the issue or not.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, and I apologize for not including all the details. Those were some of the first troubleshooting steps I tried, after I realized I could access the site on other networks I moved past IE settings and started looking at the network, although I still find it weird it loads in the other two browsers. I looked through the source code yesterday though and found a line referencing an Ad and reported back to my ISP, still waiting to hear back but my instincts tell me this may be the problem. I will report back as soon as I have an update.

Answer (score 0):

This case has been solved after working with multiple levels of support with ISP, finally able to confirm that it was indeed embedded code on the page that was calling ads that was causing the page to be blocked, although I don't see how this was only affecting IE since there doesn't even seem to be a built-in ad blocker.

To the two down votes: thanks for providing constructive criticism so I know how to improve my questions in the future.....